# Set the current execution/retry number manually for a sidekiq job with ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob, rspec-sidekiq

I have implemented retry-number dependent logic on my jobs. For example, when a job fails the first time, I restart it with additional params to handle the "clean up" of what the previous job execution may have done incorrectly.

How can I run a sidekiq job (via ActiveJob or manually) with a specific execution number

This is different than adding `sidekiq_options :retry => 5` in the class definition of the job.

I need something like

```
MyJob.set(retry_number: 2).perform_now(*args)
```

What is the syntax, or is there is a documentation that explains how to do this ?

This would prove useful

- For RSpec testing
- For manually retrying some problem jobs in the console and see the stdout /interact directly